# How to tighten chain on Kalkhoff Image 5.B Season

Tags: maintenance, chain, tension

I have [a Kalkhoff Image 5.b Season](https://www.kalkhoff-bikes.com/en_dk/kh0050094v2021-image-5-b-season) (with coaster brake) which was in need of having its chain replaced. Having moved within the last year I have been using this bike as my main way of getting to work everyday since then. I am not an experienced bike mechanic but have decided I better get the hang of it myself as it is my only means of transportation besides public transport.

Anyways, I bought a new chain and tools to do the job. But I cannot figure out how to adjust the chain tension on the bike. The dropout appears vertical to me and I have been unable to locate anything in the manual regarding adjusting the chain tension. There are several screws on the bike frame itself - and I would suspect some of them might be related to this. I have tried loosening/tightening the ones that looked the most plausible to me - but so far without any productive results.

[image: Rear wheel drive side]
[image: Rear wheel drive side 2]
[image: Rear wheel drive side 3]
[image: Front sprocket]
[image: Rear wheel brake side]
[image: Rear wheel brake side 2]
[image: Rear wheel brake side 3]
[image: Rear wheel brake side 4]
[image: Rear wheel brake side 5]

Closeup of the other side of the bolt on 2nd image:

[image]

Comment: Could you please add some photos?

Comment: Yes I will get some tomorrow when it is light outside again :)

Comment: @Berend images are added now. Note that there's a broken bolt on the brake side. It seemed to me that its only function was to hold the kickstand - so my hope was to get the chain back on the bike and get it cycling and then taking it to a shop to get the bolt removed so I can properly attach the kick stand again.

Comment: Looks like there’s a way to slide the entire dropout assembly horizontally as it’s not part of the main frame? Other than that does the motor slide forward at all or is there an eccentric bottom bracket?

Comment: @WarrenBurton I also suspect that the entire dropout can be slided (which is why I unscrewed those bolt to begin with). On the third picture it some form of assembly can be seen (albeit from a bad angle) that is tied down with 2 screws. However the way I can see it there's no room for adjusting the distance when reassembling it.

How would I go about identifying if the bottom bracket is eccentric? Do I have to remove the kranks to adjust it if that's the case?

Comment: If the BB is eccentric it looks eccentric, extra complex. There’s a few bolts to lock it in place when correct and the spindle won’t be centered in the shell. Look them up online for a photo.

Comment: That sliding part looks to me like the frame is prepared for a belt drive, since it's on the right side only.

Comment: Your BB is not eccentric

Comment: @Berend Kalkhoff makes belt drive bikes with what looks to me to be the same frame. So that would make sense.

Comment: On the 2nd picture, it looks like there a somewhat hidden bolt, just above the axle. Is that something that can be adjusted?

Comment: Yes it can. When looking at the frame itself I also thought this would be where to look. I loosened the bolts on both sides - thinking it would allow the frame to slide further back (effectively tightening the chain) - however it appeared to have no real effect.

Comment: Just to make sure, it doesn't have any effect on the position of the dropouts?

Comment: I Couldn't see or feel any difference - but having looked all over the frame I can't find a better suggestion of where to look for this adjustment. I've added a new picture trying to show the inside of that bolt. When it is completely tightened it hits a "wall".

If this is the place to look, do I just try to wriggle the dropouts loose? Or do I maybe have to loosen some of all the other bolts as well?

Comment: That last photo is kind of blurry, so it's hard to tell if we're talking about the same thing. I'll post an answer so that I can insert an image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that the bottom bracket does not seem to be eccentric, and there is no chain tensioner of any kind, I'm trying to make a guess based on the photo's.

This looks like it could be a bolt used to adjust the position of the dropouts, although it's a bit hard to tell. There should probably be a similar bolt on the left side.

[image: Possible adjuster]

Comment: I tried going out adjusting stuff again. I'm not exactly sure what did it this time, but after taking that bolt out entirely - and the similar one on the other side, as well as loosening the bolts that we suspect are there to fit a belt drive I was finally able to adjust the dropout horizontally.

Thanks a lot for helping me investigating in the right direction :)

Comment: I now managed to assemble the entire bike again (minus the broken bolt...). Thanks so much for your help! I'm both glad and frustrated that I was sort of on the right track, but would have been lovely to not break the bolt. Now I just hope I can get a local shop to sort that out for me :)

Comment: Great answer - I learned something too.  Keep up the good work !